# The entity or complex type 'DBModel.User' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
var result = db.Users.Select(x => new User() {CommpleteName=x.CommpleteName}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Estoy tratando de seleccionar una columna de mi tabla de usuario y recibo este error:

> The entity or complex type 'DBModel.User' cannot be constructed in a
>   LINQ to Entities query.

¿Qué me está faltando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes crear un `User` directamente mapeado de la Base de Datos. Si quieres hacer un `new User` debes crear un `UserDTO` para hacerlo. te explico:

1. Primero Crea tu clase [DTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx#id0080022):

   ```
   public class UserDTO
   {
       public string CommpleteName{ get; set; }
       // Crea las columnas que necesites (mismo nombre que en base de Datos)
   }
   ```
2. Edita tu método para que en lugar de devolver un `User` devuelva un `UserDTO`:

   ```
   var result = db.Users.Select(x => new UserDTO() {CommpleteName=x.CommpleteName}).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

Para clarificar un poco. Si tienes en Entity FrameWork tu modelo `User` con los siguientes campos:

```
Id
Nombre
Apellido
CommPleteName
FechaNacimiento
```

Creas la clase `UserDTO`:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Nombre{ get; set; }
    public string Apellido{ get; set; }
    public string CommpleteName{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaNacimiento{ get; set; }
}
```

De esta manera cualquier consulta con `linq` que ataque a `User` lo que harás será crear la entidad `UserDTO`.

Comment: Me dices que no es posible devolver mi modelo user con una propiedad, si no que debo crear otro modelo con la estructura que quiero deolver?

Comment: Estás haciendo un `New User` en tu consulta. Eso es lo que no está permitido.. Siguiendo la documentación de Entity Framework (te he puesto link) verás que la manera correcta es utilziando DTOs :) Son rápidos de hacer y te ayudan a separar entidad de lógica.

Comment: Entonces como logro seleccionar una sola columan de modelo original? por que el problema es que en cada select que haga y no tenga la estrutura de mi modelo tendria que crear un DTO.

Comment: En el DTO creas todas tus columnas de tu modelo independientemente de las que utilices. De esta manera lo puedes utilizar en todas tus consultas sin problema.

Comment: Entiendo, voy a probar como me dices y voy a revisar la documentacion. Pero existe una forma si la DOTs, para seleccionar columnas del modelo original?